# removing spaces from first column

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, columns

My input file has positions in first column with different number of spaces (or no space)

```
16504   16516       
    1650811   16520      
 1651   16524      
  16516111   16528       
 165204   16532
```

I need to get an output file where fist column has no spaces at all, while keeping second column as it is.

```
16504   16516       
16508   16520     
16512   16524      
16516   16528       
16520   16532
```

Comment: it's really unclear what you want,your example is a bit confusing, what do you want to do with data in first column ?

Comment: ^his comment + where did you get the "2" in 3rd line?

Comment: Dear Kiwy, Sorry my out put file shoul be same as input but removing all spaces.

Comment: Your example doesn't have different numbers of spaces, it has different lengths of numbers!

Comment: i wrote my input with different space, but i dont why it is not showing.

Comment: 16504 16516
 1650811 16520
 1651 16524
    16516111 16528

Comment: @user61398 you have to use 4 spaces on every line that is supposed to be printed verbatim (see [formatting help](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting))

Comment: The spaces show up now, I edited the question. You still need to explain the different length of numbers though.

Comment: the problem here is for this line for example: `16516111   16528` how it can become `16516   16528` where are the trainling `111` of your first column

Comment: The numbers will be kept the same but i had problem while pasting the numbers in your editor. The ouput should be in this format :                                                       16504   16516       
1650811   16520      
1651   16524      
16516111   16528       
165204   16532

Comment: @Kiwy I assume you would trim the number if too long. This needs to be explained though 1651 -> 16512 (line 3).

Comment: if you want both column properly then you can use `column -t < input_file`

Comment: Can you please edit your input data or output data so that it includes the correct data? See the "edit" link above Graeme's name, click it to edit your question to refine it.

Comment: Also, please read [formatting help](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) as peterph suggested.

Answer (score 9):

If this is just an alignment issue, and you want to line up the data into columns:

```
$ column -t somefile
16504     16516
1650811   16520
1651      16524
16516111  16528
165204    16532
```

The `-t` switch to `column` will create a table from the source data, automatically:

```
   -t, --table
          Determine the number of columns the input contains and create a 
          table.  Columns are delimited with whitespace,  by  default,
          or with the characters supplied using the separator. Table output 
          is useful for pretty-printing.
```

Comment: didn't know this tool, it's really nice

Comment: @Kiwy - yes that and `expand` is another useful tool. I use `expand` when I post examples of output that include tabs. It removes them, substituting in spaces in their place. You can control the number of spaces w/ it.

Answer (score 5):

You are likely after something like:

```
sed "s/^ *//" < your_file
```

which removes any leading spaces (replaces them with an empty string). If you also have variable number of spaces between the columns, you can extend it to:

```
sed "s/^ *//;s/  */    /g" < your_file
```

which (after removing the leading spaces) replaces any occurrence of one or more spaces with a fixed string (in this case 4 spaces). You may also want to use `\s` instead of plain space in the matching pattern to cover cases where a Tab character is used.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
awk '$1=$1' file
```

to remove all leading space in first column.